# Canvas in my View sets up as full screen dimensions, rather than View dimensions... why?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a class that extends View that I draw into.

In spite of the fact that the view is set up as a child to a RelativeLayout that has specific dimensions, the View's canvas reports that it is 1280 wide (which is as wide as the device).

I'm trying to understand what I need to do to have the canvas be constrained by the dimensions of its View (as common sense would dictate).

Curious what I'm overlooking... here are the relevant code snippets...

```
dv = new DrawView(this, getWindowManager());
    dv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    //this wrapper is 500x500
    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawWrapper)).addView(dv);
    L.log("DRAWVIEW WIDTH = " + dv.getWidth()); //this reports 0... why?
```

inside DrawView...

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    L.log("CANVAS WIDTH ON DRAW = " + canvas.getWidth()); //this always reports 1280 on xoom
    this.canvas = canvas;
    drawElementsOntoCanvas(canvas, true, false);
    ...     
}
```

Is there something I'm overlooking or is the canvas inside a View always the width and height of the entire screen?

The XML for the relative layout:

```
           <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/drawWrapper"
            android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="500px"        
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" 
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cut_out_frame"           
        />
```

Comment: I think you need to look at the onMeasure, have you read docs on custom views on Android Dev?

Comment: dv.getWidth() will be zero until after the layout is finished.   See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html.  Please show the XML for the RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Simon, adding the xml in an edit...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I see it :)

You have clipChildren = true but this applies to the containing layout.  Child views can draw outside the bounds of their parent but the drawing will simply be clipped to the parent dimensions.

It seems that here, you are using the window manager to construct your DrawView

```
dv = new DrawView(this, getWindowManager());
dv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Without seeing the constructor, I am guessing that the subsequent setLayoutParams is using FILL_PARENT, i.e. the entire screen.

If I were you, I would implement the standard constructors for your DrawView and then lay it out in the layout XML.  This is the "Android" way.  You can also override onMeasure() to track how big DrawView is, storing the x and y in internal fields, which you can use to do any scaling you need.  That way, if your layout every changes (orientation change, different resolution support, new version) your code doesn't need to change.

Finally, never (unless you REALL know why) use PX in layouts.  Use DIP instead.

Comment: thanks... px was a left-over from various attempts to try to figure out what the problem is.  I'm actually passing the WindowManager in to that DrawView because it has info that I pull later, but I'm not *using it in any relevant way for configuration. And then I set dv as a childView to the one I show in XML (which has defined dimensions).  If I don't set clip, it draws all over the screen (which is not what I want).  Oddly it reports the coords correctly starting with where the parent is sitting, so, it's honoring THAT part of the xml, but going 1280 to the right FROM there!

Comment: OK please show your constructors.  AttributeSet is the key here.  Where is it getting it from?  Either the layout manager provides it, because the view is defined in layout.xml, or you construct it.